# How to filter by pattern in a variable length Cypher query

Tags: filter, neo4j, path, variable-length

I have a very simple graph with 5 nodes (named n1 - n5), 1 node type (:Node) and 2 relationship types (:r1, :r2). The nodes and relationships are arranged as follows (apologies for the ascii art):

```
(n1)-[:r1]->(n2)-[:r1]->(n3)
(n1)-[:r2]->(n4)-[:r2]->(n3)
(n1)-[:r1]->(n5)-[:r2]->(n3)
```

I have a query using a variable length path. I expected to be able restrict the paths returned by describing a specific pattern in the WHERE clause:

```
MATCH p = (n:Node {name: 'n1'})-[*..2]->()
WHERE (n)-[:r1]->()-[:r1]->()
RETURN p
```

The problem is that the response returns all possible paths. My question; is it possible to filter the returned paths when specifying a variable length path in a query?

Comment: The response does not contain "all possible paths". It contains exactly what your query asked for: all paths of length 1 or 2 in which the first node satisfies 2 conditions - its `name` value is `n1` and it has an outgoing path of length 2 involving just `r1` relationships. If that is not what you wanted, then you have to adjust the query to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all relationships or nodes have to adhere to the same predicate, this is easy. You'll need a variable for the path, and you'll need to use `all()` (or `none()`) in your WHERE clause to apply the predicate for all relationships or nodes in your path:

```
MATCH p = (n:Node {name: 'n1'})-[*..2]->()
WHERE all(rel in relationships(p) WHERE type(rel) = 'r1')
RETURN p
```

That said, when all you want is for all relationships in the var-length path to be of the same type (or types, if you want multiple), that's best done in the pattern itself:

```
MATCH p = (n:Node {name: 'n1'})-[:r1*..2]->()
RETURN p
```

For more complicated cases, such as multiple relationship types (where the order of those types matters in the path), or repeating sequences of types or node labels in the path, then alternate approaches are needed. [APOC path expanders](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) may help.

EDIT

You mentioned in the comments that your case deals with sequences of relationships of varying lengths. While the APOC path expanders may help, it there are a few restrictions:

1. The path expanders currently operate on node labels and relationship types, but not properties, so if your expansions rely on predicates on properties, the path expanders won't be able to handle that for you during expansion, that would have to be done by filtering the path expander results after.
2. There are limits to the relationship sequence support for path expanders. We can define sequences of any length, and can accept multiple relationship types at each step in the sequence, but we don't currently support diverging sequences ((r1 then r2 then r3) or (r2 then r5 then r6)).

If we wanted to do a 3-step sequence of r1 (incoming), r2 (outgoing), then r3 or r4 (with r3 in either direction and r4 outgoing), repeating the sequence up to 3 times we could do so like this:

```
MATCH (n:Node {name: 'n1'})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(n, {relationshipFilter:'<r1, r2>, r3 | r4>', minLevel:1, maxLevel:9) YIELD path
RETURN path
```

Note that we can provide differing directions per relationship in the filter, or leave off the arrow entirely if we don't care about the direction.

Label filtering is more complex, but I didn't see any need for that present in the examples so far.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am already aware of applying predicates the way you describe. I didn't make it clear in my question but, as you mention in your last point, I am more interested in the more complicated cases where I can filter on a specific set of sequences of relationships, of varying length. I had looked at the path expanders but it wasn't clear to me how to apply these, examples seem to be pretty scarce. I'll take another look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query return all paths because your WHERE clause (Filter operator) is applied before the VarLengthExpand operator:

```
+-----------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Page Cache Hits | Page Cache Misses | Page Cache Hit Ratio | Variables                  | Other                                                                                                      |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults       |              0 |    4 |       0 |               0 |                 0 |               0.0000 | anon[32], anon[41], n, p   |                                                                                                            |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Projection           |              0 |    4 |       0 |               0 |                 0 |               0.0000 | p -- anon[32], anon[41], n | {p : PathExpression(NodePathStep(Variable(n),MultiRelationshipPathStep(Variable(),OUTGOING,NilPathStep)))} |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +VarLengthExpand(All) |              0 |    4 |       7 |               0 |                 0 |               0.0000 | anon[32], anon[41] -- n    | (n)-[:*..2]->()                                                                                            |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter               |              0 |    1 |       6 |               0 |                 0 |               0.0000 | n                          | n.name = {  AUTOSTRING0}; GetDegree(Variable(n),Some(RelTypeName(KNOWS)),OUTGOING) > 0                     |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan      |              4 |    4 |       5 |               0 |                 0 |               0.0000 | n                          | :Crew                                                                                                      |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This should get you going:

```
MATCH p = (n:Node {name: 'n1'})-[*..2]->()
WITH n, relationships(p)[0] as rel0, relationships(p)[1] as rel1, p
MATCH (n)-[rel0:r1]->()-[rel1:r1]->()
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, sequence in which the filter is applied. I need to look into the Explain plan to understand it a bit more.